# Reading Large CSV file using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv, large-files

I have to read and analyse a logging file from CAN which is in CSV format. It has 161180 rows and I'm only separating 566 columns with semicolon. This is the code I have.

```
import csv
import dtale
import pandas as pd
path = 'C:\Thesis\Log_Files\InputOutput\Input\Test_Log.csv'
raw_data = pd.read_csv(path,engine="python",chunksize = 1000000, sep=";")
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
#df
dtale.show(df)
```

I have following error when I run the code in Jupyter Notebook and it's encountering with below error message. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance!

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 348. MiB for an array with shape (161180, 566) and data type object

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import csv
import dtale
chunk_size = 1000000
batch_no=1
for chunk in pd.read_csv("C:\Thesis\Log_Files\InputOutput\Input\Book2.csv",chunksize=chunk_size,sep=";"):
    chunk.to_csv('chunk'+str(batch_no)+'.csv', index=False)
    batch_no+=1
df1 = pd.read_csv('chunk1.csv')    
df1
dtale.show(df1)
```

I used above code for only 10 rows and 566 columns. Then it's working. If I consider all the rows (161180), it's not working. Could anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance!

[I have attached the output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YL1UH.png)

Comment: I think your machine is running out of memory when trying to load in the file. I recommend splitting it into chunks and then load it in separately.

Comment: @scotmanDavid thanks for your reply. I have 12.7 GB left in my C drive.

Comment: The problem is the memory (RAM) not the storage.
Try to read only the first n-lines of the csv according to your RAM capabilities, as suggested in the previous comment.
You can use https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader

Comment: This is not about the space left on your C drive, you are running out of RAM, not ROM. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-ram-and-rom/

Comment: @Syph I have 16 GB RAM and 15.7 GB is usable.

Answer (score 0):

You are running out of RAM when loading in the datafile. Best option is to split the file into chunks and read in chunks of files

To read the first 999,999 (non-header) rows:

```
read_csv(..., nrows=999999)
```

If you want to read rows 1,000,000 ... 1,999,999

```
read_csv(..., skiprows=1000000, nrows=999999)
```

You'll probably also want to use chunksize:

This returns a TextFileReader object for iteration:

```
chunksize = 10 ** 6
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
    process(chunk)
```